# como saber qual é a ultima versão de uma biblioteca (dependencia) do Google para Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, biblioteca, android-gradle

Geralmente, quando utilizamos recursos no Android Studio, você precisa incluir bibliotecas, exemplo de um arquivo **build.gradle (Module: app)**:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    // alternatively, just LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.0"

    // Room (use 1.1.0-alpha1 for latest alpha)
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.0-alpha1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.0-alpha1"

}
```

Eu já rodei em varias página do Google, e não encontro uma forma trivial de saber qual é a última versão de cada biblioteca, sempre acho em um local alguém citando uma versão (11.2.0) já em outro (11.8.0), eu sempre utilizo a que vejo mais alta, mas isso é muito trabalhoso e nem sempre é a ultima versão lançada.

Também já tentei pesquisas do tipo no Google:

> com.android.support:appcompat-v7 last version

Isso as vezes funciona pra uma ou outra biblioteca, mas não pra toda, quero saber se o Google não possui uma página especifica definindo as ultimas versões de suas bibliotecas para Android sem precisar entrar nas páginas de documentação de cada biblioteca ou fazer várias pesquisas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No que diz respeito à appcompat em [Support Library Packages](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html) encontra a listagem de todas as bibliotecas e o respectivo identificador a utilizar no *gradle*.

Pode encontrar a listas e detalhes das revisões mais recentes em [Recent Support Library Revisions](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html).

Directamente no arquivo gradle, se colocar o ponteiro do rato sobre o identificador da biblioteca, caso haja uma versão mais recente ser-lhe-à mostrado um aviso.

Comment: 'Recent Support Library', era essa a página de referencia que precisava, obrigado. Sobre colocar o ponteiro do mouse sobre a versão da biblioteca só funciona para alguns bibliotecas cuja o 'targetSdkVersion' diferente da versão da biblioteca.

Comment: *"(...) só funciona para alguns bibliotecas (...)"* - Não é verdade, a diferença nesse caso é que o identificador da biblioteca é sublinhado com uma linha vermelha. Nos outros casos, não tem a linha vermelha mas se colocar o ponteiro a informação é mostrada.